# How to fixed the following error in python while using open-cv "Module 'cv2' has no 'CascadeClassifier' member"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am using python and open-CV to do a face matching but there i am getting the following errors?

Module 'cv2' has no 'CascadeClassifier' member
Module 'cv2' has no 'VideoCapture' member
Module 'cv2' has no 'cvtColor' member
Module 'cv2' has no 'COLOR_BGR2GRAY' member
Module 'cv2' has no 'imshow' member
Module 'cv2' has no 'waitKey' member
Module 'cv2' has no 'destroyAllWindows' member

Here is my sample.py

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascades/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        print(x,y,w,h)
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How to fixed those errors?

Comment: How did you install opencv?

Comment: using pip install opencv-contrib-python --upgrade command

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Visual Studio Code then you can follow these steps:

1. On VS Code: CTRL + Shift + P
2. Choose "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)"
3. Add this line into JSON file: "python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--generate-members"]

Steps taken from [this link](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2426#issuecomment-501526031)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you using VSCode, you can change the your code from:

```
import cv2
```

to:

```
from cv2 import cv2
```

Comment: this import is wrong and will throw an error: `ImportError: Bindings generation error. Submodule name should always start with a parent module name. Parent name: cv2.cv2. Submodule name: cv2`  it used to work in older versions of opencv, __by accident__

Answer (score 0):

It should be `pip install opencv-python`, which is the main opencv. `opencv-contrib-python` contains main open-cv and contributions of users. You should only install one of the options. Please refer to this question [The difference between opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64902852/the-difference-between-opencv-python-and-opencv-contrib-python)

Comment: not quite. `opencv-python` contains the main modules. `opencv-contrib-python` contains main + contrib modules. they should **never** be installed at the same time.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz you're right. should only install one of them