# The difference between opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python

Tags: python, opencv, pypi

I was looking at the Python Package Index (PyPi) and noticed 2 very similar packages: [opencv-contrib-python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/) and [opencv-python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) and wondering what the difference was. I looked at them and they had the exact same description and version numbers.

Comment: `opencv-contrib-python` [seems to be compiled](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/blob/a5fc2953c61ebfd6c4b0b025abbe3890edbc5a3f/setup.py#L58_L61) with [extra modules](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As per PyPi documentation:

There are four different packages (see options 1, 2, 3 and 4 below):

Packages for standard desktop environments:

> Option 1 - Main modules package: `pip install opencv-python`
>
> Option 2 -
> Full package (contains both main modules and contrib/extra modules):
> `pip install opencv-contrib-python` (check contrib/extra modules listing
> from [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/))

Packages for server (headless) environments:

> Option 3 - Headless main modules package: `pip install opencv-python-headless`
>
> Option 4 - Headless full package (contains both main modules and contrib/extra modules): `pip install opencv-contrib-python-headless`

Do not install multiple different packages in the same environment

Comment: How does the headless package differ from the non-headless package?

Comment: diff: GUI support or not. on servers, pick a headless variant. you can't present any GUI anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**opencv-python** provides the core functionality of OpenCV, including the essential image and video processing capabilities. It contains the main modules necessary for image and video I/O, image manipulation, object detection, feature extraction, and basic computer vision tasks. This package is suitable for most general computer vision tasks and is typically used as the base package for basic image processing and analysis.

**opencv-contrib-python = opencv-python + extra**

There are several additional functionalities that are not available in the standard opencv-python package, like the SIFT algorithm. So, if you need to heavily work on images and computer vision and have no hardware restrictions, definitely install opencv-contrib-python.

Answer (score -1):

Opencv has two compilations for each version, the "regular" one that is functional and well tested and the compilation with the extra components (contribs package) in their github's page they put:

> This repository is intended for the development of so-called "extra" modules, contributed functionality. New modules quite often do not have stable API, and they are not well-tested. Thus, they shouldn't be released as a part of the official OpenCV distribution, since the library maintains binary compatibility, and tries to provide decent performance and stability.

Also in contribs package there are several non-free computer vision algorithms (for features) such as SURF, BRIEF, Censure, Freak, LUCID, Daisy, BEBLID, TEBLID.